# how to specify final jar file name from command line in multi module environment

Tags: maven, jenkins, jar, pom.xml

I have a parent pom like below.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.navionics.sonarcharts</groupId>
<artifactId>distributed-task</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sonarcharts</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
<modules>
   <module>rabbitMQHandler</module>
   <module>DswJni</module>
   <module>dataInputHandler</module>
   <module>notificationEmulator</module>
   <module>modelingWorker</module>
   <module>controller</module>
   <module>contouringWorker</module>
   <module>TimerHandler</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

I am using git repository with Master and develop branches and building the system with jenkins where parent pom.xml resides.

I created 2 jobs (one for develop and one for master branch) in jenkins and building the system with mvn clean install which is producing a jar modelingWorker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar as mentioned in pom in both the cases as pom.xml is same in both branches.

Now i want to generate 2 different jar files i.e for develop it should be like modelingWorker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and for master should be modelingWorker-1.0.jar.

What are the ways of doing it? I want to have a single pom for both branches but i change command line arguments.

I mean to say single pom.xml should generate 2 jar files with 2 different names.
Please help me in finding mvn commands to generate different jar files for multiple modules.

Comment: Please reformat your question. It is very difficult to read...  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: is it difficult to read or understand?

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: i am using Apache Maven 3.0.5

Comment: You're doing the wrong thing. Maven can't do what you're asking, nor should it. You can't have a single pom for both branches -- it should be similar (probably) but not the same. The 'dev' branch should have -SNAPSHOT at the end of the version, and the master branch should not. When you merge into master, don't merge into master, merge into a release branch, in that branch change the version number, then push that into master.

Comment: The 'dev' branch should have -SNAPSHOT at the end of the version, and the master branch should not --- i did the same thing. I have different jar names for dev and master. But as per project requirement one file should not have different versions for different branches.                                    When you merge into master, don't merge into master, merge into a release branch --- you mean to say create another branch as "release" and do changes. can u explain me clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi a potential solution to your requirement - to create different jars / wars or whatever you do,is to introduce profiles. By invoking each profile on the specific job of jenkins you can configure different the plugins or your dependencies . See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: i am able to create jar files but .pom and .xml files are getting added to artifactory when i do mvn deploy. are there any tags that i can include in pom.xml so that it does not deploy .pom and .xml files into artifactory. Here is my pom.xml.
<repository>
<id>myrepo.example.com</id>
<name>myrepo.example.com</name>
<url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
<id>myrepo.example.com</id>
<name>myrepo.example.com</name>
<url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/</url>
<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
</snapshotRepository>